# Python pandas how to duplicate certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe row:

```
key1 key2 key3 val1 val2 val3 .. valn
 a    b    c     1   2     3      14
```

I want to duplicate the value columns:

```
key1 key2 key3 val1_0 val2_0 val3_0 .. valn_0 val1_1 val2_1 val3_1 .. valn_1
 a    b    c     1     2      3          14     1       2     3      14
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use `pd.concat([df,df.filter(like="val")],axis=1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
s = df.filter(like='val')
df = pd.concat([df.drop(s.columns,1),s.add_suffix('_0'),s.add_suffix('_1')],axis=1)
df
Out[106]: 
  key1 key2 key3  val1_0  val2_0  ...  valn_0  val1_1  val2_1  val3_1  valn_1
0    a    b    c       1       2  ...     NaN       1       2       3     NaN
[1 rows x 11 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to iterate on your columns, check if it is numerical and duplicate it.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]})

columns = df.columns
for col in columns:
    if is_numeric_dtype(df[col]):
        df[col + '_1'] = df[col]
print(df.columns)
>> ['A','B','B_0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the column names from df.columns. Then do a string manipulation like add something that is unique to the df columns names. Then loop through the new column names in the assignment part and assign the old column to it.

Pseudo code

```
for x in df.columns:

    df[x+"new"] =df[x]
```